# In Hibernate, how can I handle different data types on the same entity field?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, db2

I have a entity like this mapped by Hibernate:

```java
@Entity
public class MyTable {
  // ...
  private String myMessage;
  // Getters...
}
```

I have to support both Oracle and DB2, but this particular column has different types in the schemas for the two databases: in Oracle schema it is `VARCHAR2(2000)` and in DB2 it is `CLOB`.

Now, if I leave it as is, it works for Oracle and breaks on DB2, if I annotate `myMessage` with `@Lob` it works on DB2 but breaks on Oracle.

Since I can't change the schema, what is the best way to handle this situation? I was thinking something like a custom Hibernate type, but I'm not sure.

Note that the entity is read-only, I'm not interested in persisting data at the moment.

Comment: As the JPA spec and any decent JPA docs would tell you, you can provide an `orm.xml` to map to a particular datastore (rather than hardcoding things in annotations). Hardcoding mapping info in annotations is always a dumb idea when you want to consider other datastores for an application